# JOpenChart dates on x axis

Tags: java, graph

I am trying to use JOpenChart, unfortunately, the documentation stinks, not even a javadoc as far as I can see.

My problem is that I am trying to use a date on the x axis, and I don't see how this is done.  The tutorial implies that I need to use ObjectChartDataModel, but the constructor takes DataSet[] instead of DefaultDataSet[], which is probably fine.  I assume one can polymorph to the other (hard to know for sure because, no javadoc is provided), but it takes an Object[] as a second parameter and I have no idea what that is.

Does anyone know this tool that can either answer my question or at least point me at where the documentation exists.  The only documentation he seems to offer is this: http://jopenchart.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html which is nice, but doesn't really cover all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/ or if you can afford it http://www.jidesoft.com/products/charts.htm. I've used both and they each have their strengths. The chart you are trying to use I never had much luck with.